# The tag [jsonconvert] should be a synonym of [json.net]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

The tag [jsonconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonconvert) is just people asking about the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) library, whose primary object is `JsonConvert`. It should be a synonym of the [json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net).

I don't have enough rep in this tag to suggest the synonym. *In a related rant*, how is this supposed to work? Obviously I won't have enough rep to suggest a synonym in an invalid tag.

So can we synonymise this tag, please?

Comment: Relevant for the rant: [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/369403), from MSE back in 2012. They're well aware it doesn't, and have been for almost a decade now.

Comment: Relevant to this request: the current tag wiki of [[tag:jsonconvert]] is : *"This tag can be used when you want to convert any text, objects or other formats into a JSON object, or if you want to transform a JSON object into something else."* so it should either be changed, or invalidate this request...

Comment: Almost all of the questions tagged jsonconvert are about Json.Net. There are a handful actually about what the wiki (vaguely suggest) but they are in a minority. I'd say it's clear that the vast majority of people are actually referring to Json.Net.

Comment: Reading your question I assumed that `jsonconvert` was indeed a synonym. But on 141 question taged `jsonconvert`, 33 doesn't have `.net`,  `json.net`, nor `c#` tag. 23%. And the definition of the tag doesn't match the proposed solution.https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1402268

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [tag usage breakdown](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?tagname=jsonconvert), I agree with your assertion that this tag is *largely* used for Json.NET. 92 out of the 141 total questions are tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), which is a near guarantee that a given question is referencing [json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net) (and should probably be tagged as such).

However, I disagree that these tags should be merged, since we'd lose the more general definition of the [jsonconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonconvert) tag.

The tag wiki excerpt states:

> This tag can be used when you want to convert any text, objects or other formats into a JSON object, or if you want to transform a JSON object into something else.

Even though this is fairly general, I think there's still utility here, and that this tag should stick around. The [jsonconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonconvert) tag, as defined by its wiki, is a superset of [json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net), and this means that they aren't synonyms. The fact that a quarter of the questions ([34 total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonconvert+-json.net+-c%23)) in this tag *aren't* apparently about Json.NET tells me that synonymizing these tags would be a mistake, and that we'd lose an otherwise useful tag by getting rid of the former.

---

#### Addendum

Regardless of whether or not you feel we *should* have a tag for converting data to/ from JSON, the tag wiki and usage of these two tags is demonstrably not synonymous, and therefore should not be synonymized as-is.

With this in mind, I think our options are:

1. Clean-up the tag to remove *non*-Json.NET usages, and then synonymize to [json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net)
2. Burn [jsonconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonconvert), if there's community consensus that the tag shouldn't exist

Either of these are valid, but the tag still shouldn't be synonymized without cleanup; this would tag at least 35 questions with a tag irrelevant to those posts.

Comment: We don't need a tag for people wanting to convert random object from/to json. We need tags about libraries (if they aren't part of the standard) that do these tasks.

Comment: A better tag to represent the act of converting something to JSON would be [json-serialization], if it was actually needed (see [xml-serialization] as an example; it only has 826 questions whereas there are 4288 question with both [xml] and [serialization]). Personally, I don't think a tag for general "convert something to json" considering that [json] can be used for that just as easily, optionally with [serialization].